# WSO2 ESB HTTP POST with form data

Tags: wso2, esb, apache-synapse

I have a soap service that I want to turn around and post a message to an external server.

I was able to do this via curl like so:

```
curl  --data-urlencode "filename=data.txt" --data-urlencode "filedir=/home/myfile/in" 
      --data-urlencode "busproc=MyBP" --data-urlencode "serverip=192.168.1.4" 
      --data-urlencode"uid=myuserid" --data-urlencode "pwd=mypwd"
      http://somelocation.com:8833/webservice/inbound/here
```

But I can't quite get it working correctly.  Here's my proxy service:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ExampleHTTPPostWithFormData"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="post" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://somelocation.com:8833/webservice/inbound/here"
                        format="pox"/>
               <property name="uid" value="user"/>
               <property name="pwd" value="password"/>
               <property name="filedir" value="/home/myfile/in"/>
               <property name="busproc" value="myBP"/>
               <property name="serverip" value="192.168.1.4"/>
               <property name="filename" value="data.txt"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

The end service seems to only see me posting to the URL (but not the passed in data properties).

Answer (score 3):

Properties are not the way to build the message content. The best way I've found to do it is with a `payloadFactory`. The message you need to build has a root XML element with one child per form field, and then it seems that Axis2 handles the `messageType` of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by serialising in the appropriate format. So a minimal change to your proxy would be:

```xml
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="ExampleHTTPPostWithFormData"
       transports="http"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log/>
         <property name="messageType"
                   value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                   scope="axis2"
                   type="STRING"/>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
           <format>
             <params xmlns="">
               <uid>user</uid>
               <pwd>password</pwd>
               <filedir>/home/myfile/in</filedir>
               <busproc>myBP</busproc>
               <serverip>192.168.1.4</serverip>
               <filename>data.txt</filename>
             </params>
           </format>
         </payloadFactory>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://somelocation.com:8833/webservice/inbound/here"
                        format="rest"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
         <log level="full"/>
      </inSequence>
   </target>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

It may also be convenient to add `<property name="FORCE_HTTP_1.0" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>` depending on whether your REST service handles HTTP/1.1.

If you need parameters then you can pass in arguments to the `payloadFactory`, using the [XPath extensions](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Synapse+XPath+Variables). E.g.

```xml
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
           <format>
             <params xmlns="">
               <uid>user</uid>
               <pwd>password</pwd>
               <filedir>/home/myfile/in</filedir>
               <busproc>myBP</busproc>
               <serverip>192.168.1.4</serverip>
               <filename>$1</filename>
             </params>
           </format>
           <args>
             <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$ctx:filename"/>
           </args>
         </payloadFactory>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your sending the SOAP payload in a file you would need to use the VFS transport. Please refer to the following sample on how to use the VFS transport to solve your issue

```
http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838852
```

Alternatively you can use SOAPUI or any SOAP client to send the payload directly to the ESB proxy endpoint

Comment: why would I use VFS to post to a website?  While the above has file information in it, that's not the goal.  The goal is to do a HTTP post with form data.

Comment: the link is not working

Answer (score 0):

For 6.5.0, without changing anything under axis2.xml, i used the following code:

```
     <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
                <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Body>
                        <root>
                            <password>3525251</password>                           
                        </root>
                    </soapenv:Body>
                </soapenv:Envelope>
            </format>
            <args>
           </args> 
    </payloadFactory>         

               
  <property name="messageType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
  <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" value="true" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>

 // then here you put the rest call normally
```

Note: the message type should be after the payload and not before, otherwise it wont work (at least for me).